# Display number of items in TextView after async task in Android

Tags: android, listview

I call a web service which fetches 0-n items which are displayed in a ListView in an Android activity.

In my onCreate() I have

```
new GetData().execute();
```

Which populates an object called customerDataList.

And in the onPostExecute I use a list adapter to display the returned data.

Above the ListView I would like to display the number of items retrieved, however if I do something like this:

```
new GetData().execute();
TextView numberOfItemsElm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_of_items);
numberOfItemsElm.setText(customerDataList.size());
```

0 is displayed because that line is run before the execution has finished.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 0 is displayed because that line is run before the execution has finished.

That is exactly right

So, move these lines

```
TextView numberOfItemsElm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_of_items);
numberOfItemsElm.setText(customerDataList.size());
```

to your `onPostExecute()` after setting the adapter on your list.

Alternatively, you could place the code to set the text in a method which is called in `onPostExecute()` in case you use that code somewhere else in the `Activity`.

Although, that should actually throw a `ResourceNotFoundException` since you are sending an int as the param. It should be something like

```
numberOfItemsElm.setText("" + customerDataList.size());
```

Comment: It will cast it to a String. Same thing if you use `String.valueOf(customerDataList.size())`